# What will happen to the files under domain after changing to a workgroup

Tags: domain, files, workgroup

I recently change from domain to a workgroup because of trust issue error, unfortunately I forgot to backup all my files in the domain, is it possible to recover my files after returning to the domain again?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, when a domain member system leaves a domain, all that happens is the Security IDs (SIDs) of the domain accounts will no longer be recognized by the system. Rejoining the domain should make them recognizable again, with no other actions needed.

And even if I'm wrong, as long as you have local admin access, you can always first *take ownership* of any files, then re-assign their permissions however you want. So that's your Plan B in case simply rejoining the domain doesn't work.